# How can heap objects use data from the stack?

Tags: c, pointers

I've declared the `struct` foo like this:

```
struct foo {
    const char* name_lower; 
    const char* name_caps
    //..
};
```

I dynamically create instances of `foo` on the heap and want to save a value in the `name_lower` and `name_caps` member variable. This is done by the function `bar`

```
void bar(foo* entry, const char* str, int delimiter_pos) {

    char l[2] = {str[caps_pos-1], '\0'}; // create new string
    char c[2] = {str[caps_pos+1], '\0'};

    entry->name_lower = &l[0]; // assign these strings the foo instance
    entry->name_caps =  &c[0];
}
```

I am worried, because I don't know if this code is going to crash. The temporarily created arrays `l` and `c` will be saved on the stack. Once the function terminates the stack will be cleared up and `c` and `l` will probably disappear.

Does this mean that the `foo` instance will lose its names, i.e. its references? If so,  how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Google for "dynamic memory allocation" - http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: I know the principles about dynamic memory allocation. Does this mean I must store l and c on the heap by calling malloc?

Comment: Yes, exactly. otherwise they will point to the address which will contain undefined values after the flow returns from `bar` .

Comment: Yes, because after the function's body ends, the pointers shouldn't be dereferenced.

Comment: Another way of putting that is when the function terminates the function stack frame is destroyed along with all variables local to the function. So you must copy `1` and `c` to new blocks of memory within `bar` and assign the start address of the new blocks to `entry->name_lower` and `entry->name_caps`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, the easiest way to allocate/copy and assign the start address for new blocks of memory for `l` and `c` is to use `strdup` (from `string.h`):

```
void bar(foo* entry, const char* str, int delimiter_pos) {

    char l[2] = {str[caps_pos-1], '\0'}; // create new string
    char c[2] = {str[caps_pos+1], '\0'};

    entry->name_lower = strdup (l); // assign these strings the foo instance
    entry->name_caps =  strdup (c);
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory allocated to `entry->name_lower` and `entry->name_caps` when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use `char *l = (char *)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));` and then initialize it; similarly for `char *c`. Then set `entry->name_lower = l; entry->name_caps = c;`

When allocating make sure you check whether the allocation succeeded, i.e. whether `malloc` returned non-NULL address.

Make sure you free the memory after you don't need it anymore: `free(entry->name_lower); free(entry->name_caps);`.

Answer (score 0):

It will not **lose** anything. The pointers in the `struct` will retain their value, but the content will change and you will eventually get SIGSEGV.

For the `char *` to persist, you need to allocate it on the heap too.

```c
void bar(foo* entry, const char* str, int delimiter_pos) {
    char * l = malloc(2);
    char * c = malloc(2);
    /* Check l and c for NULLs */

    l[0] = str[caps_pos-1];
    l[1] = '\0';
    c[0] = str[caps_pos+1];
    c[1] = '\0';

    entry->name_lower = l;
    entry->name_caps = c;
}
```

Remember that you should also `free()` the struct members when you will no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limit on the length of your strings, you can use `char` arrays instead of pointers. In your example, all strings have a length of 1. Assuming your strings cannot be longer than that, you can use `char[2]` instead of `char*`:

```
struct foo {
    char name_lower[2];
    char name_caps[2];
    //..
};

void bar(foo* entry, const char* str, int delimiter_pos) {
    entry->name_lower[0] = str[caps_pos-1];
    entry->name_lower[1] = '\0';
    entry->name_caps[0] = str[caps_pos+1];
    entry->name_caps[1] = '\0';
}
```

Historical note:

Because this is so easy to use, people got accustomed to this, and forced artificial limits on string length, leading to buffer overflows. If your strings are not limited, use dynamic allocation instead of `char` arrays.